# how to toggle the icons using image sprites

Tags: jquery-ui

In my side navigation bar there is a list of icons. Icon which is active, must be changed into another icon. At the moment we click another icon in the list, previous icon must be changed into original first icon.

```js
jQuery(".login-normal").click(function() {
  jQuery(".login-normal").toggleClass("login-sel");

});
jQuery(".images-nor").click(function() {
  jQuery(".images-nor").toggleClass("images-sel");
});
```

```css
.images-nor,
.images-sel,
.login-normal,
.login-sel {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("spr.png") no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  text-align: left;
}

.images-nor {
  background-position: -0px -0px;
  width: 66px;
  height: 63px;
}

.images-sel {
  background-position: -0px -63px;
  width: 66px;
  height: 63px;
}

.login-normal {
  background-position: -0px -952px;
  width: 47px;
  height: 60px;
}

.login-sel {
  background-position: -0px -1012px;
  width: 47px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vertical-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="login-normal"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="images-nor"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image given is a image sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAKtU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your code and I do not see any issues. Made some minor adjustments to ensure the example works properly, yet as you can see below when you run the snippet, it is working.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".login-normal").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".login-normal").toggleClass("login-sel");
    $(".images-nor").removeClass("images-sel");
  });
  $(".images-nor").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".images-nor").toggleClass("images-sel");
    $(".login-normal").removeClass("login-sel");
  });
});
```

```css
.vertical-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.images-nor,
.images-sel,
.login-normal,
.login-sel {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAKtU.png") no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  text-align: left;
}

.images-nor {
  background-position: -0px -0px;
  width: 66px;
  height: 63px;
}

.images-sel {
  background-position: -0px -63px;
  width: 66px;
  height: 63px;
}

.login-normal {
  background-position: -0px -952px;
  width: 47px;
  height: 60px;
}

.login-sel {
  background-position: -0px -1012px;
  width: 47px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vertical-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="login-normal"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="images-nor"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: if i click the login it must be changed to blue color.it is working well. but when we click the images , image must be changed to blue color , at the same time login must be changed to white color.help me

Comment: @VISHNUCR you had not clarified that in your post. So you want  the user to be able to select one of the icons, but not both. If they select the Image icon, the Lock should be toggle off and vice versa?

Comment: @VISHNUCR I have updated the code and added the opposing `.removeClass()` to each. If this helps, please upvote and mark it as an answer. If not, comment and let me know what is not working.